# webshot does not render local images inside html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, phantomjs

I'm using node-webshot and phantomjs-cli to render an html string to a png image.
The html contains an image tag.  The image is not rendered when it is the src attribute points to a local file and no error is raised.  However it does render the image when the src points to a http location.  I've tried all of the different file path combinations that I can think of, eg

```
<img src=images/mushrooms.png"/>
<img src=images//mushrooms.png"/> 
<img src=c:\images\mushrooms.png"/>
<img src=c:\\images\\mushrooms.png"/>
<img src=file://c:\\images\\mushrooms.png"/>
<img src=file://images//mushrooms.png"/>
etc..
```

but so far no luck.  Interestingly it works fine on my colleague's machine which is a Mac but not on mine which is Windows, and I've tried with two different Windows machines with no success.

Here is some simplified code that focuses on the issue:

```
'use strict'

const webshot = require('webshot');

console.log('generating');

webshot('<html><head></head><body><img src="c:\\images\\mushrooms.png"/></body></html>', 'output.png', {siteType: 'html'}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});

/*
webshot('<html><head></head><body><img src="https://s10.postimg.org/pr6zy8249/mushrooms.png"/></body></html>', 'output.png', {siteType: 'html'}, function(err) {  
    console.log(err);      
});
*/
```

The commented out code block is an example of it working with a web link as the image source but I need it to work off of a local path.

Has anyone had this issue before an know how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: It would be quite dangerous if browsers could just open random files from the local file-system - guessing you can't just host the files locally on Apache or somesuch?

Comment: it could be a security measure of your browser indeed (see https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/7f8e1bc1-f4be-4274-840c-73f1aab092b2/allow-blocked-content-javascript-on-local-html-files-ie11?forum=ieitprocurrentver for example)

Comment: thanks for your replies.  I'm running the script under nodejs and not in a browser.  I can use fs to read local files and this code works fine on a Mac, just doesn't seem to work in windows.

Comment: Is the image part of the node.js project or just on the machine somewhere else?

Comment: As the first 2 path you provide is a relative path, I think it may be related to the position of the image files.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  The image is just in a folder on the machine, i.e. it is not a part of the nodejs project.  thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Local files should be accessible via the `file:` URI Scheme:

`<img src="file:///C:/images/mushrooms.png">`

Per the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#section-3.10):

```
A file URL takes the form:

   file://<host>/<path>
```

Comment: This worked for me so I've awarded to bounty to you.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to set static folders.

Use something like this in your code `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Learn more about it [here](http://www.fullstacktraining.com/articles/how-to-serve-static-files-with-express).

Answer (score 1):

Can be because you never open the quotes.
try:

```
<img src="images/mushrooms.png"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Likely a `phantomjs` problem, I've run into bugs before and they barely maintain the project to this date. You should consider switching to [Headless Chrome](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md), which is new and officially maintained by the Chromium team.

Edit: here's an example

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent('<html><head></head><body><img src="c:\\images\\mushrooms.png"/></body></html>');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'output.png'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Edit 2: [here's the link the node package](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/)

Comment: Thanks for that. I would like to use Chrome headless if possible but I'm still unable to get the image to render. Were you able to render the html with the image? I am getting a broken image icon rendered which to me means it cannot find the image. I have tried different file path formats but no luck. I added a div with some text and the text renders fine but not the image. –

Comment: Did you try to load the webpage directly? Try creating a `test.html` file with the html contents and open it in Chrome. Use the DevTools to debug. You probably have some error on the path format or similar :)